# R restores workspace without .RData file

Tags: r

When I start R from a terminal, I see:

```
Type 'q()' to quit R.

[Previously saved workspace restored]

>
```

But that directory has no `.Rdata` file

```
$ ls *.RData
ls: *.RData: No such file or directory
$ ls *.Rdata
ls: *.Rdata: No such file or directory
```

The problem is that functions saved in this previous workspace are in the global environment and cover functions that I defined since:

```
Attaching package: ‘PosteriorBootstrap’

The following objects are masked _by_ ‘.GlobalEnv’:

    anpl, get_rstan_file, load_dataset, script, stick_breaking
```

How can I find the location of the `.Rdata` file that R loads on startup? And how can I prevent R from doing this automatically in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is probably there, your command just doesn’t show it: `*.RData` expands to any file ending in the string `.RData`, *except* `.RData` itself.

Do this:

```sh
ls .RData
```